# Custom View attribute and functions unreachable from Fragment (Using DataBinding)

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, custom-view, two-way-binding

What I'm trying to accomplish here, is to create an custom view of ConstraintLayout wrapping a InputTextLayout and also edittext,along with a textView.
However the setting functions aren't working when setting in fragment(**DataBinding**). And also with the edittext, I was hoping to try **two-way binding** for **LiveData** and **Observer**.

**Please try to approach with Kotlin**

Attrs.xml

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="ErrorCasesTextInputLayout">
    <attr name="isPass" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="errorCase" format="enum">
        <enum name="empty" value="0"/>
        <enum name="format" value="1"/>
        <enum name="identical" value="2"/>
    </attr>
    <attr name="text" format="string" value=""/>
    <attr name="hint" format="string" value=""/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Custom View Layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="15sp">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/custom_error_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This field is required"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/errorRed"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/custom_text_input_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/custom_text_input_layout"/>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Custom View Class

```
class ErrorCasesTextInputLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

private var _errorCase: Int
private var _isPass: Boolean
private var _hint: String?
private var _text: String?



init {

    LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.custom_error_case_text_input_layout, this, true)

    attrs.let {
        val attributes =
            context.obtainStyledAttributes(it, R.styleable.ErrorCasesTextInputLayout)

        attributes.apply {
            try {
                _isPass = this.getBoolean(R.styleable.ErrorCasesTextInputLayout_isPass, true)
                _errorCase = this.getInteger(R.styleable.ErrorCasesTextInputLayout_errorCase, 0)
                _hint = this.getString(R.styleable.ErrorCasesTextInputLayout_hint)
                _text = this.getString(R.styleable.ErrorCasesTextInputLayout_text)
                
                mSetErrorCase()
                mSetPass()
                mSetHint()

            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }

    }
}

fun setErrorCase(caseType: Int) {
    _isPass = false
    _errorCase = caseType
    invalidate()
    requestLayout()
}

private fun mSetHint() {
    val editText = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.custom_edit_text)

    if (_hint != null ) {
        editText.hint = _hint
    }

}

private fun mSetPass() {
    val layout = findViewById<View>(R.id.custom_text_input_layout)

    if (_isPass) {
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_edittext)
    } else {
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_edittext_error)
    }

}

private fun mSetErrorCase() {
    val errorText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.custom_error_message)
    val layout = findViewById<View>(R.id.custom_text_input_layout)
    when (_errorCase) {
        0 -> {
            errorText.text = EdittextErrorCase.EMPTY.errorMessage
            errorText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_edittext_error)
        }
        1 -> {
            errorText.text = EdittextErrorCase.FORMAT.errorMessage
            errorText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_edittext_error)
        }
        2 -> {
            errorText.text = EdittextErrorCase.UNIDENTICAL.errorMessage
            errorText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_edittext_error)
        }
    }
}

fun setPass(pass: Boolean) {
    _isPass = pass
    invalidate()
    requestLayout()
}

fun setText(text: String) {
    _text = text
    invalidate()
    requestLayout()
}

fun setHint(hint: String) {
    _hint = hint
    invalidate()
    requestLayout()
}

fun getCurrentErrorCase(): Int {
    return _errorCase
}


@InverseBindingMethods(InverseBindingMethod(
    type = ErrorCasesTextInputLayout::class,
    attribute = "bind:text",
    event = "bind:textAttrChanged",
    method = "bind:getText")
)
class CustomEditTextBinder {
    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("textAttrChanged")
        @JvmStatic
        fun setListener(view: ErrorCasesTextInputLayout, listener: InverseBindingListener) {

            val input: TextInputEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text)
            input.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{

                override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                    listener.onChange()
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                }
            })
        }

        @BindingAdapter("text")
        @JvmStatic
        fun setTextValue(view: ErrorCasesTextInputLayout, value: String?) {
            if (value != view._text) view.setText(value.toString())
        }

        @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "text", event = "textAttrChanged")
        @JvmStatic
        fun getTextValue(view: ErrorCasesTextInputLayout): String? = view._text
    }

}
```

}

Working Fragment

```
class ChangeNumberFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var binding: FragmentChangeNumberBinding
private val viewModel by viewModels<ChangeNumberViewModel> { getVmFactory() }

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = FragmentChangeNumberBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    binding.editTextNumber.setHint("Enter New Number")
    binding.editTextNumber.setPass(true)

    viewModel.newNumber.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

        if (it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            binding.editTextNumber.setErrorCase(1)
        } else {
            Logger.i(it)
            binding.editTextNumber.setPass(true)
        }
    })

    return binding.root
}
```

}

Two-Way Binding with liveData

```
app:text="@={viewModel.newNumber}"
```

Comment: The first thing come to my mind is that DataBinding inflates after returning View, therefore when calling binding.customView.setText(""), the view isn't created yet.
But I'm still eager to know how to accomplish the 2-way binding and to set Attributes programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

After a day of researching and try error, I manage to success on the two-way binding.

It was an obvious error that I didn't assign the editText view to the getText method, and with an incorrect form of null handling on setText.

```
class CustomEditTextBinder {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter(value = ["textAttrChanged"])
        fun setListener(view: ErrorCasesTextInputLayout, listener: InverseBindingListener?) {
            if (listener != null) {
                view.custom_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                    override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

                    }

                    override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

                    }

                    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                        listener.onChange()
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "text")
        fun getText(view: ErrorCasesTextInputLayout): String {
            return view.custom_edit_text.text.toString()
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("text")
        fun setText(view: ErrorCasesTextInputLayout, text: String?) {
            text?.let {
                if (it != view.custom_edit_text.text.toString()) {
                    view.custom_edit_text.setText(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps for those who are also facing the same problem.